# Send Post Request WebClient C# .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, web

I'm trying to send a POST request to a WebService, but I'm getting a (308 permanent redirect) error, I'm using System.Net.WebClient (All the program works in .Net 2.0 so I can't use System.Net.Http)
Here is my code (makeRequets() method returns XML below this block)

```
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {


                    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";

                    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(makeRequest());


                    byte[] result = client.UploadData(connection, "POST", data);
                    string resultContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
                }
```

This is the content I'm trying to send.(It works in postman)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns="something.com/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <procesarLotePorFacturaRequest xmlns="something.com/">
            <procesarDocumento>
                <rDE>
                    <DE>
                        <gOpeDE>
                            <iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>
                        </gOpeDE>
                        <gTimb>
                            <iTiDE>1</iTiDE>
                            <dNumTim>14601619</dNumTim>
                            <dEst>9</dEst>
                            <dPunExp>9</dPunExp>
                            <dNumDoc>22712</dNumDoc>
                        </gTimb>
                        <gDatGralOpe>
                            <dFeEmiDE>2022-04-12T12:34:56-04:00</dFeEmiDE>
                            <gOpeCom>
                                <iTipTra>1</iTipTra>
                                <iTImp>1</iTImp>
                                <cMoneOpe>PYG</cMoneOpe>
                            </gOpeCom>
                            <gEmis>
                                <dRucEm>80005366</dRucEm>
                                <dDVEmi>4</dDVEmi>
                            </gEmis>
                            <gDatRec>
                                <iNatRec>1</iNatRec>
                                <iTiOpe>1</iTiOpe>
                                <dRucRec>5307630</dRucRec>
                                <dDVRec>3</dDVRec>
                                <iTiContRec>1</iTiContRec>
                                <dNomRec>BARRETO MENDEZ EDER MATIAS</dNomRec>
                                <dDirRec>A</dDirRec>
                                <dNumCasRec>0</dNumCasRec>
                                <cPaisRec>PRY</cPaisRec>
                                <dDesPaisRe>Paraguay</dDesPaisRe>
                            </gDatRec>
                        </gDatGralOpe>
                        <gDtipDE>
                            <gCamFE>
                                <iIndPres>1</iIndPres>
                            </gCamFE>
                            <gCamItem>
                                <dCodInt>614143297809</dCodInt>
                                <dDesProSer>R CAPELETIS - POLLO 500GR PAQ </dDesProSer>
                                <dCantProSer>3.00</dCantProSer>
                                <gValorItem>
                                    <dPUniProSer>12500</dPUniProSer>
                                    <dTotBruOpeItem>37500</dTotBruOpeItem>
                                    <gValorRestaItem>
                                        <dDescItem>0</dDescItem>
                                        <dTotOpeItem>37500</dTotOpeItem>
                                    </gValorRestaItem>
                                </gValorItem>
                                <gCamIVA>
                                    <iAfecIVA>1</iAfecIVA>
                                    <dTasaIVA>10</dTasaIVA>
                                </gCamIVA>
                            </gCamItem>
                            <gCamCond>
                                <iCondOpe>1</iCondOpe>
                            </gCamCond>
                        </gDtipDE>
                        <gTotSub>
                            <dSubExe>0</dSubExe>
                            <dSub5>0</dSub5>
                            <dSub10>37500</dSub10>
                            <dTotOpe>37500</dTotOpe>
                            <dRedon>0</dRedon>
                        </gTotSub>
                    </DE>
                </rDE>
                <parametrosProcesamiento>
                    <retornarKuDE>true</retornarKuDE>
                    <retornarXmlFirmado>true</retornarXmlFirmado>
                    <templateKuDE>1</templateKuDE>
                    <forzarReingreso>false</forzarReingreso>
                    <docAsociado>
                        <numero>1575</numero>
                        <tipo>4</tipo>
                    </docAsociado>
                </parametrosProcesamiento>
            </procesarDocumento>
        </procesarLotePorFacturaRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: .NET 2.0 went out of support over a decade ago. The earliest supported version is 4.6.2 which *does* support HttpClient. Why are you targeting .NET 2 at all? All supported Windows versions come with 4.6.x

Comment: In any case 308 is a valid response, not an error. Web services follow a specific protocol, SOAP, you don't just call them with WebClient. All .NET versions can generate WCF proxy classes that will call the services directly, from the service's WSDL. Right click on your project's References and select `Add Service Reference`

Comment: Do you know if the endpoint is configured for http or https and have you double checked the endpoint?

Comment: Check [Tutorial: Create a Windows Communication Foundation client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-create-a-wcf-client). The generated client will have methods for every service operation and DTOs for every service object. HTTPS and security will be handled based on the instructions of the WSDL document